# Centos7 docker-py doesn't seem to be installed

Tags: docker, ansible, centos7

I installed Centos7 minimal and then: ansible, docker, pip and using pip I installed docker-py.

Versions: 
- Docker version 1.6.0, build 8aae715/1.6.0 
- ansible 1.9.1 
- docker_py-1.2.2

Trying to run a playbook, for example

```
- name: redis container
  docker:
    name: myredis
    image: redis
    state: started
```

i get msg: `docker-py` doesn't seem to be installed, but is required for the Ansible Docker module.

I can't see the problem. Is it the CentOS, docker and ansible version?

PS: I disabled the firewalld and SELinux

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Can you show your Dockerfile ?

Comment: I don't have a Dockerfile. I'm using  ansible-playbook -i hosts.ini playbook.yml
This playbook has one task that i wrote in the post.

You meant something else or ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a couple problems with the docker-py module. After I worked through them I ended up with this:

```
  - name: Docker-PY
    pip:
      name: "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
    - six==1.4
    - docker-py==1.1.0
```

First, I ran into your problem. The solution is to explicitly set the most recent version of six as described here: https://github.com/docker/docker-py/issues/344.

After that, I ran into an issue (you might run into it too) with a bug in the docker-py 1.2.2 version. The workaround is to specify an older version as described here: https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/1227. Do a pip uninstall docker-py to get rid of the newer version.

If you aren't using ansible to install these then do this:

```
[sudo] pip uninstall docker-py
[sudo] pip install six==1.4
[sudo] pip install docker-py==1.1.0
```

Answer (score 8):

If you're working on CentOS7 or similar, you may not want to install unpackaged code via pip. In which case, it's good to know that the Extras channel has a package `python-docker-py`. I had this problem, installed that package, and was off to the races.

Comment: The name `python-docker-py` is a little bit confusing, as `docker-py` is required by Python<2.7 version and I wanted to use the last one, `docker`. But in fact, `python-docker-py` installs the python module `docker` (you can check with `repoquery --list python-docker-py`). So `yum install python-docker-py` is just perfect

Comment: Sorry, `python-docker-py` installs the version 1.10.6 of `docker`. This is not fine at all

Answer (score 3):

### tl;dr;

check file permissions and make sure your user can read the python module in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages

### Context

I recently went to this is issue but it was a permission problem.

Note that I used docker 1.9.1, ansible 2.0.1.0 and redhat 7.2.

I installed docker-py with ansible (this might not be your case).

I did it with this role:

```
- name: install docker-py with pip
  become: true
  pip: state=present name='{{ item }}'
  with_item:
    - docker-py==1.2.3
    - six==1.10.0
```

### Problem

When sudoing, ansible may install docker-py with default umask 0077. As a result, no user, except root, will be able to read docker-py module files.

Your playbook will result with the `docker-py doesn't seem to be installed, but is required for the Ansible Docker module` error.

Notice the differences between:

- `sudo pip install docker-py` => `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker` is in mode 0700
- `sudo su` then `pip install docker-py` => `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker` is in mode 0755

### Fix

This will be fixable with ansible 2.1 by passing the `umask=0022` parameter to the pip module (see https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/commit/4b46200477216dbcc54611d1c3e6f0cc83757aaf).

For now I fixed it by removing all packages installed in mode 0700:

```
pip uninstall -y six docker-py websocket_client
```

Then reinstalling them by hand:

```
sudo su
# now umask is 0022
pip install six==1.10.0 docker-py==1.2.3
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a variation of this issue recently. It wasn't due to my using `sudo` to install the module, but the other way around.

For whatever reason I opted to install `docker` using pip's `--user` flag and then had the unfortunate "idea" to use the `-b` or `--become` option.

This resulted in the "obviously" installed `docker` module being unavailable to the elevated Ansible instance running my playbook. Sharing in case someone has "one of those days" and stumbles across this later on. Hope it helps you as I paid for this reminder with a good bit of "stupid tax", hopefully enough for the both of us. :)