# Ansible cannot import docker-py even though it is installed

Tags: python, docker, pip, ansible

I checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30350881/centos7-docker-py-doesnt-seem-to-be-installed) and followed the fix in both answers and neither worked.  I'm opening a new post partly because of that and partly because I'm getting a slightly different error even though the problem might be the same.

Ansible host:

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.1.0.0
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
```

Destination client myserver:

```
$ pip list | egrep 'six|docker|websocket_client'
docker-py (1.2.3)
six (1.10.0)
```

test.yml:

```
---
- hosts: myserver
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
  - name: stop any running docker registries
    docker_container:
      name: registry
      state: stopped
...
```

Ansible server (ansible-playbook aliased to ap):

`$  ap -vvvv test.yml`

The output:

(probably extraneous output, snipped):

```
fatal: [myserver]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "failed": true,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "api_version": null,
            "blkio_weight": null,
            "cacert_path": null,
            "capabilities": null,
            "cert_path": null,
            "command": null,
            "cpu_period": null,
            "cpu_quota": null,
            "cpu_shares": null,
            "cpuset_cpus": null,
            "cpuset_mems": null,
            "debug": false,
            "detach": true,
            "devices": null,
            "dns_opts": null,
            "dns_search_domains": null,
            "dns_servers": null,
            "docker_host": null,
            "entrypoint": null,
            "env": null,
            "etc_hosts": null,
            "exposed_ports": null,
            "filter_logger": false,
            "force_kill": false,
            "groups": null,
            "hostname": null,
            "image": null,
            "interactive": false,
            "ipc_mode": null,
            "keep_volumes": true,
            "kernel_memory": null,
            "key_path": null,
            "kill_signal": null,
            "labels": null,
            "links": null,
            "log_driver":
            "json-file",
            "log_options": null,
            "mac_address": null,
            "memory": "0",
            "memory_reservation": null,
            "memory_swap": null,
            "memory_swappiness": null,
            "name": "registry",
            "network_mode": null,
            "networks": null,
            "oom_killer": null,
            "paused": false,
            "pid_mode": null,
            "privileged": false,
            "published_ports": null,
            "pull": false,
            "read_only": false,
            "recreate": false,
            "restart": false,
            "restart_policy": null,
            "restart_retries": 0,
            "security_opts": null,
            "shm_size": null,
            "ssl_version": null,
            "state": "stopped",
            "stop_signal": null,
            "stop_timeout": null,
            "timeout": null,
            "tls": null,
            "tls_hostname": null,
            "tls_verify": null,
            "trust_image_content": false,
            "tty": false,
            "ulimits": null,
            "user": null,
            "uts": null,
            "volume_driver": null,
            "volumes": null,
            "volumes_from": null
        },
        "module_name": "docker_container"
    },
    "msg":
```

(the pertinent error):

`"Failed to import docker-py - cannot import name NotFound. Try pip install docker-py"}`

I get the same error when I downgrade the docker-py module to 1.1.0 as per the first answer in the referenced post.  I  also tried to chmod the directories and it made no difference:

```
(/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages) myserver$ ls -lad docker*
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root root 4096 Jul  4 10:57 docker/
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Jul  4 10:57 docker_py-1.2.3-py2.7.egg-info/
```

from `chmod -R go+rx docker*`.

Has anyone seen this before?  I have tried using the pip ansible module to install the modules and then after removing them manually, reinstalled them manually as in the referenced post.  I'm also using 2.1.0.0. as you can see, which was supposed to fix this issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because new versions of python modules `docker` and `docker-py` that ansible uses are incompatible. I had to revert back and explicitly specify the following versions of PIP packages:

- docker: 2.0.0
- docker-py: 1.10.6

Sample playbook task for these:

```
- name: install certain python modules for docker
  pip:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    version: "{{ item.version }}"
    state: present
  with_items:
  - { name: docker, version: 2.0.0 }
  - { name: docker-py, version: 1.10.6 }
```

All my play books work fine since then.

Comment: It appears that with certain versions there is a clash in the package names : "Cannot have both the docker-py and docker python modules installed together as they use the same namespace and cause a corrupt installation"

Answer (score 7):

For me specifying the path to `docker-py` worked.

```
- hosts: <host>
  environment:
    PYTHONPATH: "/home/path/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages"
```

Basically Ansible was looking in the wrong directory.

Full credit to Clay Graham for his great article on the issue:

https://medium.com/dronzebot/ansible-and-docker-py-path-issues-and-resolving-them-e3834d5bb79a

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the problem... For me, the problem was that the remote Docker host (RHEL7) had installed the python-urllib3 package into /usr/lib/python2.6/, instead of /usr/lib/python2.7/. Extending the PYTHONPATH in my Ansible script as described by Clay Graham got me going again.

Answer (score 6):

TL;DR

Don't use the `--user` flag for pip to install `docker` module and then use the `-b` or `--become` flag for `ansible-playbook` because the elevated playbook instance won't see the `docker` module that is installed for a different user.

---

In hindsight it was probably obvious to everyone else why I was running into an issue, but for whatever reason I opted to install `docker` using pip's `--user` flag and then had the unfortunate "idea" to use the `-b` or `--become` option.

This resulted in the "obviously" installed `docker` module being unavailable to the elevated Ansible instance running my playbook. Sharing in case someone has "one of those days" and stumbles across this later on. Hope it helps you as I paid for this reminder with a good bit of "stupid tax", hopefully enough for the both of us. :)

Comment: This was actually the most useful answer I found on here

Answer (score 2):

Got the same problem on the remote server (Debian 10) using ansible 2.4.3.0 and python2 as interpreter

I've tried a lot of combinations docker, docker-py, docker-compose pip modules with different versions, but it started to work only after

```
apt-get install python-docker
```

on the server machine

It also could be installed via playbook

```
- name: Install required system packages
  apt: name=python-docker state=latest update_cache=yes
```

Answer (score 1):

The requirements for the docker-py module on ansible's documentation for the docker* modules is not really up-to-date, but generally here are some ansible - docker-py pairs that should work:

- Ansible 2.1.0.0 requires docker-py version 1.7.0 at least, which in turn requires at least docker 1.9 installed on the client.
- If you need to use an older version of docker, then you can use docker 1.7 with ansible 2.0.1.0 and docker-py 1.4.0.
- If you need an even older version of docker, like 1.6 then you are stuck with ansible 1.9

Comment: Cheers, but as I've got 2.1.0.0 on the server, and have tried 1.7.0 docker-py with 1.11 docker to !avail. I have a workaround for any frustrated people out there which is to always start the registry container with name=registry and then in the playbook use `docker ps --filter=name=registry -q` and register the output as a var, then use shell commands such as `docker stop {{ docker_regID.stdout }}` etc.

Comment: @SztupY  do you mean the remote has to have Docker installed or the local has to have it installed? Is it actually communicating through the Docker Daemon?

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem. Details description:

- I run ansible from machine where was Ansible version 2.9.11.
- On my machine where I would to deploy was Ansible version 2.9.11 too, but it doesn't works and I got error:  `"Failed to import docker or docker-py - cannot import name __version__. Try pip install docker or pip install docker-py (Python 2.6)"}`.

How to solve the problem in my case:

```
Just downgrade Ansible version from 2.9.11 to 2.7.9 on machine where you would to deploy.
```

1. Remove you Ansible package (in my case I install Ansible with pip):

   ```
   pip uninstall ansible
   ```
2. Install version of Ansible 2.7.9:

   ```
   pip install ansible==2.7.9
   ```

In my case it work like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to use `state: forcereinstall` option while installing `docker` pip module and the issue went away!!

After adding the following main task/action, before calling any other main tasks/actions or importing other yml file based tasks, worked!!

-- When this option was not used, Ansible's docker installation was showing `ok: ...` i.e. docker is already installed but then later, other actions where I used `docker_*` ansible modules, were still giving me the above `no named module` errors.

```
# If forcereinstall is removed, you may get an error i.e. no module found 
#
- name: "Force Install 'docker' pip module"
  pip:
    name: docker
    extra_args: "--no-index --find-links={{ docker_SDK_Python_dest_path_where_I_see_bunch_of_whl_or_tar_gz_files }}"
    state: forcereinstall
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this on to your 'hosts' file:

Change `[servers:vars]` to `[your-group-of-server-names:vars]`

For Python >= 2.7

```
[servers:vars]
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3 # For Python3 [default Ubuntu-18.04]
```

Python <= 2.7

```
[servers:vars]
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python # For Python2.7
```