# Ansible cannot import docker-py even though it is installed (Ansible 2.3.0.0)

Tags: python, docker, ansible

I'm having the same problem as [volvox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/259453/volvox) who asked the orginal question but on Ansible 2.3.0.0 when I use the advice in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41493058/1064619) from [anoxis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3588244/anoxis) to his post.

Steps to reproduce:

I created a new VirtualEnv:

```
zoidberg:foley chris$ virtualenv ansible-test
New python executable in /Users/chris/src/hc/foley/ansible-test/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in /Users/chris/src/hc/foley/ansible-test/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
```

Installed Ansible:

```
(ansible-test) zoidberg:foley chris$ pip install ansible
Collecting ansible
Collecting pycrypto>=2.6 (from ansible)
Collecting paramiko (from ansible)
  Using cached paramiko-2.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting jinja2 (from ansible)
  Using cached Jinja2-2.9.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in ./ansible-test/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from ansible)
Collecting PyYAML (from ansible)
Collecting cryptography>=1.1 (from paramiko->ansible)
  Using cached cryptography-1.8.1-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_10_intel.whl
Collecting pyasn1>=0.1.7 (from paramiko->ansible)
  Using cached pyasn1-0.2.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.23 (from jinja2->ansible)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.6.0 in ./ansible-test/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from setuptools->ansible)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=16.8 in ./ansible-test/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from setuptools->ansible)
Requirement already satisfied: appdirs>=1.4.0 in ./ansible-test/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from setuptools->ansible)
Collecting idna>=2.1 (from cryptography>=1.1->paramiko->ansible)
  Using cached idna-2.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting enum34 (from cryptography>=1.1->paramiko->ansible)
  Using cached enum34-1.1.6-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting ipaddress (from cryptography>=1.1->paramiko->ansible)
  Using cached ipaddress-1.0.18-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting cffi>=1.4.1 (from cryptography>=1.1->paramiko->ansible)
  Using cached cffi-1.10.0-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.whl
Collecting asn1crypto>=0.21.0 (from cryptography>=1.1->paramiko->ansible)
  Using cached asn1crypto-0.22.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing in ./ansible-test/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from packaging>=16.8->setuptools->ansible)
Collecting pycparser (from cffi>=1.4.1->cryptography>=1.1->paramiko->ansible)
Installing collected packages: pycrypto, idna, enum34, ipaddress, pycparser, cffi, asn1crypto, cryptography, pyasn1, paramiko, MarkupSafe, jinja2, PyYAML, ansible
Successfully installed MarkupSafe-1.0 PyYAML-3.12 ansible-2.3.0.0 asn1crypto-0.22.0 cffi-1.10.0 cryptography-1.8.1 enum34-1.1.6 idna-2.5 ipaddress-1.0.18 jinja2-2.9.6 paramiko-2.1.2 pyasn1-0.2.3 pycparser-2.17 pycrypto-2.6.1
```

Checked the version:

```
(ansible-test) zoidberg:foley chris$ ansible --version
ansible 2.3.0.0
  config file =
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
  python version = 2.7.13 (default, May 14 2017, 22:38:03) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)]
```

Installed the versions of docker and docker-py suggested in this answer:

```
(ansible-test) zoidberg:foley chris$ pip list | grep docker
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
docker (2.0.0)
docker-py (1.10.6)
docker-pycreds (0.2.1)
```

But I still get the same error:

```
(ansible-test) zoidberg:foley chris$ ansible-playbook -i inventory/local build.yml -vvvv
No config file found; using defaults
Loading callback plugin default of type stdout, v2.0 from /Users/chris/src/hc/foley/ansible-test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/__init__.pyc

PLAYBOOK: build.yml **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
1 plays in build.yml

PLAY [Build foley docker images] *********************************************************************************************************************************************
META: ran handlers

TASK [docker_image] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /Users/chris/src/hc/foley/build.yml:12
Using module file /Users/chris/src/hc/foley/ansible-test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/cloud/docker/docker_image.py
<localhost> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: chris
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~ && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /Users/chris/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1494837576.9-236428678313889 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1494837576.9-236428678313889="` echo /Users/chris/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1494837576.9-236428678313889 `" ) && sleep 0'
<localhost> PUT /var/folders/zn/cfj4ng250293z1g5s19w3zdh0000gn/T/tmp_SRwg6 TO /Users/chris/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1494837576.9-236428678313889/docker_image.py
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /Users/chris/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1494837576.9-236428678313889/ /Users/chris/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1494837576.9-236428678313889/docker_image.py && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python /Users/chris/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1494837576.9-236428678313889/docker_image.py; rm -rf "/Users/chris/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1494837576.9-236428678313889/" > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
fatal: [127.0.0.1 -> localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "failed": true,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "api_version": null,
            "archive_path": null,
            "buildargs": {
                "PRIVATE_REPO_PASSWORD": "6c50ef3a91e9b5cd47251f921f3fb53d1e53afa5",
                "PRIVATE_REPO_USERNAME": "hexagonalwax"
            },
            "cacert_path": null,
            "cert_path": null,
            "container_limits": null,
            "debug": false,
            "docker_host": null,
            "dockerfile": null,
            "filter_logger": false,
            "force": false,
            "http_timeout": null,
            "key_path": null,
            "load_path": null,
            "name": "honeycomb/foley",
            "nocache": "False",
            "path": ".",
            "pull": true,
            "push": false,
            "repository": null,
            "rm": true,
            "ssl_version": null,
            "state": "present",
            "tag": "latest",
            "timeout": null,
            "tls": null,
            "tls_hostname": null,
            "tls_verify": null,
            "use_tls": "no"
        }
    },
    "msg": "Failed to import docker-py - No module named docker. Try `pip install docker-py`"
}
  to retry, use: --limit @/Users/chris/src/hc/foley/build.retry

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
127.0.0.1                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Here's my playbook:

```
(ansible-test) zoidberg:foley chris$ cat build.yml
---
- name: Build foley docker images
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false

  vars_files:
    - "ansible/vars/build_secrets.yml"

  tasks:

    - docker_image:
         path: .
         name: worldofchris/foley
         buildargs:
           PRIVATE_REPO_USERNAME: "{{ PRIVATE_REPO_USERNAME }}"
           PRIVATE_REPO_PASSWORD: "{{ PRIVATE_REPO_PASSWORD }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
```

And my inventory:

```
(ansible-test) zoidberg:foley chris$ cat inventory/local
[localhost]
127.0.0.1 ansible_connection=local
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Appleman](https://github.com/Applemann) over on the [Ansible GitHub issues page](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/20492) I have a fix for this which is to run Ansible with Python 3:

```
foley chris$ ansible-playbook -i inventory/local build.yml -e ansible_python_interpreter="/usr/local/bin/python3"

PLAY [Build foley docker images] ***********************************************************************************************************

TASK [docker_image] ************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [127.0.0.1 -> localhost]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************
127.0.0.1                  : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Thanks [techraf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2947502/techraf) and [Konstantin Suvorov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2795592/konstantin-suvorov) for your help on this.